# Cast property of reflected object back to its original type

Tags: swift, reflection, generics

All this is about wrapping any object or type (=Any) and to be able to check if types are equal later. Works fine with a class as wrapper for the type and the value. My problem is that i want to throw in an object, find its properties through reflection and to create a wrapper for each property with the (wrapped) type of that property. Problem is that the reflected properties are always of Type Any - i would need to cast to their real type (String for example).

Example will clear things up:

```
// Functions to check equality of Types
func unsafeGetTypeId(type: Any.Type) -> uintptr_t {
    return unsafeBitCast(type, uintptr_t.self)
}
func areOfSameType(v1: Any, v2: Any) -> Bool {
    return unsafeGetTypeId(reflect(v1).valueType) == unsafeGetTypeId(reflect(v2).valueType)
}

class ZType {

}

class ZTypeT<T> {
    var value: Any?
    init() {

    }
    init( value: T ) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class SampleClass {
    var sampleProperty : String
    init( aString: String ) {
        self.sampleProperty = aString
    }
}

var sample = SampleClass(aString: "Hans")

var t1 = ZTypeT<String>()
var t2 = ZTypeT(value: sample.sampleProperty)
areOfSameType(t1, t2) // true

var mirror = reflect(sample)
for var index=0; index<mirror.count; ++index {
    let (propertyName, childMirror) = mirror[index]

    var tTestAgainst = ZTypeT<String>()

    // This is obviously of type Any so it won`t be ZTypeT<String>() but ZTypeT<Any>()
    var tMirrorProp = ZTypeT(value: childMirror.value)
    areOfSameType(tMirrorProp, tTestAgainst) // false

    // So how could i cast the value back to it`s type? This would work but it should be generic : i don`t know the type beforehand
    var tMirrorPropCasted = ZTypeT(value: childMirror.value as String)
    areOfSameType(tMirrorPropCasted, tTestAgainst) // false
}
```

As you can see all works as expected until tMirrorProp because this won't be of type String. If i cast it my check will again be true - but well i can't cast without knowing the type. Does anybody know a solution to solve this. A solution working with Swift-Classes is preferred but a solution which works with NSObject(s) is still interresting.

Comment: Maybe this code can help. It's capable of parsing an object back and forward to a dictionary. https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/blob/master/AppMessage/AppMessage/CloudKit/EVReflection.swift

Answer (score 0):

As you already say the only way to instantiate the correct type is by casting the childMirror.value to the correct type. You could do that by adding a switch for each type. Then compare the objects using `NSStringFromClass(tMirrorPropCasted.dynamicType)` You would get something like:

```
var tMirrorPropCasted : ZTypeT<Any>

var theValue = anyValue
let mi:MirrorType = reflect(theValue)
if mi.disposition == .Optional {
   if mi.count == 0 { // Optional.None
      theValue = NSNull() 
   } else {
      let (name,some) = mi[0]
      theValue = some.value
   }
}

switch(theValue) {
        case let intValue as Int:
            tMirrorPropCasted = ZTypeT(value: childMirror.value as Int)
        case let doubleValue as Double:
            tMirrorPropCasted = ZTypeT(value: childMirror.value as Double)
        case let stringValue as String:
            tMirrorPropCasted = ZTypeT(value: childMirror.value as String)
        case let boolValue as Bool:
            tMirrorPropCasted = ZTypeT(value: childMirror.value as Bool)
        case let anyvalue as NSObject:
            tMirrorPropCasted = ZTypeT(value: childMirror.value as NSObject)
        default:
            tMirrorPropCasted = ZTypeT(value: childMirror.value)
        }
```

But instead of checking the type of the objects you could also check the type of the value properties. That property will still have the information of it's original type. So what you could do is testing

```
if NSStringFromClass(tTestAgainst.value.dynamicType) == NSStringFromClass(tMirrorProp.value.dynamicType) {
   NSLog("Same type")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since i want to use reflection testing agains types is not an option (this is a special case of "knowing the type" IMO though it should work with classes i do not know of) :) You are right about checking the values instead of the type, actually this is my current workaround. But sad but true - this will fail with optionals. I will have to wait for an improved relfection library i think. One thing makes me think so, the apple devs told me that they use the reflection only for tool output. I have to check if optionals in reflection are logged as Optional-String e.g.  ..

Comment: You can test for optionals (sort of). You could check for reflect(theValue).disposition == .Optional Then if reflect(theValue).count == 0 then the value is nil and you can't get the type, otherwise you can get the reflect(theValue).[0].1.value

Comment: I updated the answer with additional code for optionals

Comment: Yes i can get the type if it is not optional. But how to find out if an optional is a Optinal-String or Optional-Double..

Comment: see the added code to the answer. You test for mi.disposition == .Optional and then you can use the some.value and see if it's a Double. If both conditions are right, you have an optional Double.

Comment: Well but this will still only work if there is a value. If an Optional.String is nil it won`t work or am i overseeing something?

Comment: That's true. Let's hope Apple will improve the reflection possibilities of swift soon.